# "quite common" or "very common"

Tags: word-choice

> The following scenario is **quite** common in physics.

I am sure **very** is ok here, but how about **quite**? Which is better?

Answer (score 4):

You may find [this article](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/pretty-fairly-really-very-and-quite) helpful. It does a good job overviewing the differences between words used to add degrees of intensity (i.e. *very*, *really*, *quite*, *pretty*, *extremely*, etc.).

Both words are perfectly fine to use. The difference I think is that *very* is a **stronger intensifier**, so saying "very common" indicates that the scenario is especially common, more so than it might be if you were to say "quite common".

Answer (score 4):

> The following scenario is quite/very common in physics'.

Both are intensifier and both can be used here, but I can't say one is better and one is not because they convey different meanings.

*Very* is used for emphasis to make the statement more intense and stronger.

> Very common(=it's not just common, but really common)

Quite tells you that the degree of intensity is noticeable or significant and more than expected

> Quite common(=noticably common)

Source: [Leanersdictionary.com](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/pretty-fairly-really-very-and-quite)